# jquery ajax call class webmethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I would like use jquery mobile to an exist asp.net webform apps. Now I am thinking use pure html control to do the jqm page. I know when I make ajax call I can call the code behind static webmethods. Since they are public and static. I am thinking make a central class to handle those data accessing.
My question is can I use ajax call some url like "class/webmethods";

your suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: is the mobile code on the same application?

Comment: Yes. I create a mobile folder. I can create aspx page to do this no problem. but the problem I wanna try use html page now. to call central class to get json data.

Comment: so you will not have any cross domain issues which is good, i usually create a webService for say .asmx and a class where this webService methods call this class the return its methods statment

Comment: @Mina, Thanks for your suggestion. I am very interested in this approach. Can you show me any example pls.

Comment: http://www.scriptiny.com/2012/12/calling-asmx-web-service-via-jquery-ajax-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a Generic Handler (ashx) to handle your AJAX requests?  If you don't need the page's life cycle, I would recommend this approach.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I am very interested in this approach. Can you show me any example pls.

Comment: i don't understand why not using `.asmx` instead   ?

Comment: I suppose it's personal preference @MinaGabriel.  I only use .asmx to communicate between two different applications.

Comment: @AgLong here is a nice summary calling a handler from jQuery: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev

Comment: @JonathanCarter, so every ashx file has one method? If I have a lot of functions need connect db,  I have to create a lot ashx files? Thanks

Comment: @MikeLong I target various methods within a generic handler through querystring parameters.  You can keep all your methods in one file with this approach.  Here's a nice article on that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353260/ASP-NET-Advanced-Generic-Handler-ASHX